# Where can I report suggested edit reviewers who approved a harmful edit?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, suggested-edits

With harmful edits I don't mean minor edits, but edits like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4768302) where there's an issue in the code, and the edit fixes said code. This can cause editors to continue fixing code in questions or answers, and that's very bad.

I've brought up a few edits in the Tavern previously, but I'm not sure if this is the best way to handle these.

Comment: Wouldn't a (polite) comment informing the editor that his  edit is wrong, be more helpful? Unfortunately the reviewers can't be notified this way.

Comment: It's worth noting that if this edit was in an answer the edit would be entirely fine (if the edit is correct from a technical standpoint, something I'm not qualified to judge).  It's only a problem because it's in a *question*.

Comment: What's interesting about this is that the answers reflect the original unedited form. Are you absolutely sure that is incorrect?  In general, I would recommend against modifying code in a question, as an error there may well be part of the problem the poster is having - I'd point the issue out in a comment or in my answer if I was providing a more complete one.

Comment: I fix errors in code all the time. Who says this is a problem? Just yesterday, I made [this edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/23492886/revisions) to an answer, in order for me to be able to upvote it. And [this edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/23536807/revisions). Feel free to report me to a moderator, I suppose. There are plenty more examples in my profile.

Comment: It's important not to fix errors in *questions*, because that can invalidate the question altogether.  I've seen questions (admittedly, these were "how do I shot web?" type questions) where *fixing the indentation* removed the bug the poster wanted help with!  And no, they were not Python questions `;-)`  I'm all for fixing errors in *answers*, although personally I prefer to point out the problem in comments and let the original poster make the actual edit.

Comment: @CodyGray: I think you've misunderstood the problem. The edit that Stijn refers to is an edit to the *question*: the OP was asking why his/her code didn't work, and someone edited the code so that it *did* work (but the question still asked why it didn't).

Comment: Yes, I missed that the first time around. I later noticed. I think it bears qualification. There is a harmful sentiment some people seem to espouse regarding editing code in answers. Obviously questions are an entirely different case.

Comment: 'Tis interesting that both the answers contain the typo that was 'fixed' in the question by the flawed edit.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Flag the post in question, and explain the situation using a custom flag.  The moderator can then investigate the reviewers and take whatever action they feel is warranted.

Comment: Definitely consider integrating your comment (above) in your answer. Editing code in *questions* is not a good idea. Editing code in *answers* to fix obvious mistakes is a great idea. There's no point leaving a comment nagging someone to fix a typo.

Comment: @CodyGray Unless it's a typo for an unused language where it can't be expected for a reviewer to evaluate it's technical accuracy.

Comment: Meh, it just has to wait for the right reviewer. Maybe the poster herself. The Skip button is there for a reason. If you're really improving the answer, you should be encouraged to edit, obscure specialty or not.

Comment: @CodyGray The example is just that; an example.  Discussing it here would simply be a distraction from the actual question.  I don't want this to turn into a debate over when and how one should be editing code in posts.